# How to run unit tests without using Selenium?

Tags: magento-1.9, unit-tests, phpunit, mtf

Is it possible to run MTF without using Selenium?

The main aim is to run tests on the web-server (Running Debian), we don't have any web browsers on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

Magento is having a work around for this with phpunit facebook webdriver. But still you need selenium. See the note at the end in the documentation.

Reference:

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/mtf/features/webdriver.html